# PHP: Trouble reading file in an upper directory

Tags: php, fopen

On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I am trying to read a file with PHP, called from a browser ([www.domain.com/program.php](http://www.domain.com/program.php)), that is located just above the public_html directory:

```
$myfile = fopen("/var/www/domain.com/file.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("/var/www/domain.com/file.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
```

*Warning: fopen(file.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/domain.com/public_html/program.php on line 37
Unable to open file!*

The file is there.
Is this a permissions issue?
Is there a way for a php program called from a browser to access a file that is not in the public_html directory?

Comment: Have you tried using relative path? `../file.txt`

Comment: Yes, it does not work either.

Comment: Ok that's interesting. fopen has a specific error for permission denied. Can you confirm the code works for a file in the same directory?